# How to open exchange message storage using MAPI without additional dialogs

Tags: c#, exchange-server, mapi

I'm use MAPI32.dll to get access to user mails. Currently I am doing the following

```
   MAPI.LogonEx(IntPtr.Zero, profileName, null, MAPI.FLAGS.Extended | MAPI.FLAGS.NewSession | MAPI.FLAGS.AllowOthers | MAPI.FLAGS.NoMail, out mapiSession);
    ...
   mapiSession.OpenMsgStore(IntPtr.Zero, ENTRYID.Create(rows[0, 0]), Guid.Empty, IMAPISession.FLAGS.BestAccess | IMAPISession.FLAGS.MdbOnline | IMAPISession.FLAGS.MdbTemporary | IMAPISession.FLAGS.MdbNoMail, out mdb);
```

I'm use IMAPISession.FLAGS.MdbOnline to get messages directly from Outlook server. This successfully connects me to user inbox which I can then loop through. But this code causes the dialog to enter user credentials. Can anyone suggest any "quiet" way to **get messages without dialog boxes**?

Will be glad to any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the credentials during the connection to the messagestore. this will make the mapi layer to continue without re-asking for them.

Comment: How can i do this? The profilePassword parameter in LogonEx method is ignored on all Win32 platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange provider always uses the identity of the current user (parent process-wise), but it also uses the credentials cache. You should be able to cache the credentials using CredWrite() before opening the store.